# Sharing Models between ExtJS 4 apps

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, model, share

I have many apps in my ExtJS project. I have a model which should be available in every app. So I have to redefine it for each app. Is there any way to use this model for other apps? I tried to add the model by its full namespace. But it didn't work.

So, Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a project structure like this:

`root

  - models

    - mymodel

        MyEntity.js

    - myothermodel

        MyOtherEntity.js

  - app1

      index.html

      app.js

  - app2

      index.html

      app.js

  - app.. N

      index.html

      app.js`



Add `Ext.Loader.setPath("MySharedModels", "../models");` at top of your projects app.js, then you can reference your entities consistently:
"MyEntity" class can be reached as `MySharedModels.mymodel.MyEntity` and
"MyOtherEntity" class can be reached as `MySharedModels.myothermodel.MyOtherEntity`